# SQL group by over two joins

Tags: mysql, sql

These are my tables:

```
create table articles(
    id integer auto_increment,
    site varchar(64) not null,
    title varchar(512) not null,
    link varchar(512) not null,
    pub_date datetime not null,
    primary key(id)
);

create table entities (
    id integer auto_increment,
    entity varchar(1024) not null,
    entity_type varchar(32) not null,
    primary key(id)
);

create table articles_entities (
    article_id integer not null,
    entity_id integer not null,
    foreign key(entity_id) references entities(id),
    foreign key(article_id) references articles(id)
);
```

This is the starting point of what I am trying to do:

```
select count(*), entity_type from entities group by entity_type;
```

I obviously get something that looks like this:

```
+----------+---------------+
| count(*) | entity_type   |
+----------+---------------+
|    15418 | locations     |
|    21789 | misc          |
|    62306 | organizations |
|   121307 | people        |
+----------+---------------+
```

What I want is something like this:

```
+----------+---------------+------+
| count(*) | entity_type   | site |
+----------+---------------+------+
|    15418 | locations     | ABC  |
|    21789 | misc          | ABC  |
|    62306 | organizations | ABC  |
|   121307 | people        | ABC  |
|    13418 | locations     | CNN  |
|    22789 | misc          | CNN  |
|    65306 | organizations | CNN  |
|   132307 | people        | CNN  |
+----------+---------------+------+
```

How can I set up that query to provide that sort of counting?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And then `JOIN` again.

Comment: ... what is your problem? Did you try to join the three tables together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a `join`:

```
select count(*), entity_type, site 
from entities 
left join articles_entities on entity_id = entities.id
left join articles on article_id = articles.id
group by entity_type, site;
```

I used a `left join` on the assumption that you may have entities that don't correspond to articles that you want included in the results. If this is not the case then you can remove the `left`s.